# Almost periodic compactification with the Gelfand-Naimark theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, topological-groups, c-star-algebras, locally-compact-groups

Could anyone please help me with a bibliographic reference presenting the almost periodic compactification of a topological group with the aid of the Gelfand-Naimark theorem?

Rudin in "Fourier Analysis on Groups" and Hewitt and Ross in "Abstract Harmonic Analysis" use different methods, and I would like to present this compactification as a consequence of the Gelfand-Naimark theorem.

Comment: If you are not thinking of abelian groups only, please change "Gelfand-Naimark" to "Gelfand-Naimark-Segal".

Comment: @guest: Right now I am studying Chapter 2 in Kaniuth's "A Course in Comutative Banach Algebras" where he does the construction for non-commutative (but locally-compact) groups. So no, it has nothing to do with the GNS construction or with commutativity. Could you be more precise, please?

Comment: What is the commutative Banach algebra to which you would apply the Gelfand-Naimark theorem?

Comment: @The $\Bbb C \ *$-algebra of the (left-) almost periodic functions on $G$, which is a closed $\Bbb C \ *$-subalgebra of the $\Bbb C \ *$-algebra of bounded continuous functions. Apparently you had something else in mind.

Comment: I think we are talking about different notions of almost-periodicity, but I am confused about which notion you are referring to.  For instance, in a finite group $G$ all functions in $\mathbb{C}[G]$ are Bohr-almost periodic, but this group algebra is not commutative if $G$ is not commutative.

Comment: @guest: A finite group is compact, and for compact groups, indeed, all continuous functions are almost periodic. You are talking about the complex group algebra, I am talking about a subalgebra of the algebra of functions $C_b (G) = \{ f : G \to \Bbb C \mid f \ \text{continuous} \}$. More precisely, $AP(G) = \{ f \in C_b (G) \mid \{L_x f\} _{x \in G} \ \text{ is relatively compact in } C_B(G) \}$.

Comment: @guest: Of course not! It is the *space* of functions, not the *algebra*.

Comment: All right, I got it.  My stupidity got the better of me.  You were not talking about the convolution product.